# Username Login Case Insensitive ? PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I've find a login script using PHP that connects to a admin table from a MySQL DB.
My issue is that the username is case sensitive and I don't want it to be. All usernames will be proper names so it will work even the username use upper or lower case.

```
<?php
session_start();

require('connect.php');
if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($count == 1) {

        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    } else {
        echo "Invalid Login Credentials.";
    }
}
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    header("location:index.php?page=user");

    echo "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
} else {
    ?>
    <div class="register-form">
        <?php
        if (isset($msg) & !empty($msg)) {
            echo $msg;
        }
        ?>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <p><label>User Name : </label>
                <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" /></p>

            <p><label>Password&nbsp;&nbsp; : </label>
                <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" /></p>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
        </form>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `Collation` in your DB table, find the field that's case sensitive and go to `change`, make sure it's `latin1_swedish_ci` , some options force it to be case sensitive.

If that isn't your problem, change the `=` signs to `LIKE` in your `$query`.

`ci` at the end of your `Collation` option means `Case Insensitive`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to alter your database you can also force the case before checking the login. For example:

```
// Convert the username all lowercase
$username = strtolower($_POST['username']);

// Use LOWER() to convert the username to lowercase
$query = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE LOWER(username)='$username' and password='$password'";
```

On a separate note, please look into `mysqli` and prepared statements. The code you included is very insecure (lookup SQL Injection).